# Object that calls a method on Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable, try-finally

Is there a .NET class which calls a method when it gets disposed, sometimes instead of:

```
try
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    MyCleanupMethod()
}
```

I'd like to:

```
using(new OnDisposed(MyCleanupMethod))
{
    ...
}
```

Before I get berated, for three reasons:

- For long `try` blocks it allows the reader to see what needs to be cleaned up at the start
- `try` has an implication that its catching an error (which it's not)
- To keep the disposal code `private` (if the `IDisposable` object is returned from a class)

Is this valid practice? If so, is a .NET class which does this?

Comment: Nothing to stop you writing it yourself, but I have to say that 'try-finally' is standard, much clearer to C# developers and fits your use case just fine.

Comment: You could do this yourself. Include a constructor parameter that is a function in your object that implements IDisosable.  Call the function in OnDispose

Comment: I don't say I agree with your second point, `try/finally` is a perfectly common construct, I doubt any experienced developer will presume you must be necessarily catching something. But I would find your syntax also acceptable, as long as it's used consistently.

Comment: @Baldrick on the contrary, not only is it *customary* to use `Dispose` for cleanup, it's so common that the language added `using` in .NET 1.1. This is a very, very common pattern.

Comment: @c-z the Dispose pattern is so common that .NET languages have special keywords to make it easier (`using` in C#, `use` in F#). Wrapping a resource with an IDisposable is a valid choice although it would be better if that resource implemented IDisposable itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Not disputing that `using` is normal. Perfectly good construct. But creating an artificial object to encapsulate cleanup *just so you can use it with using*, when a try-finally would work just fine, seems unnecessary and potentially confusing. But each to their own! It's not a horrible idea by any means.

Comment: @Baldrick on the contrary, the Dispose pattern is used extensively. `using` was added to make the `try/finally for purposes of cleanup` easier to use. As for artificiality - why should the *caller* have to know what to cleanup? It's not his concern at all. `try/finally` actually leaks the cleanup code into the caller

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Just a personal opinion, but as a C# developer who uses both try-finally and `using` regularly, the try-finally approach is clearer and more readable in this case *for me*. But I fully respect your opinion, as it's based on well a reasoned argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a constructor that takes the action:

```
public class OnDisposed : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _disposeAction;
    public OnDisposed(Action disposeAction)
    {
        _disposeAction = disposeAction;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ...
        if(_disposeAction != null)
            _disposeAction();
    }
}
```

For example:

```
using (new OnDisposed(() => Console.WriteLine("Dispose Called")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("In using...");
}
```